# How do geneticists compute the percentage of DNA shared between species?

Tags: genetics

It's not exactly clear to me what is meant when people say that humans and bananas share 50% of their DNA.

Comment: There is a good question in here I think. Currently it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking. Could you provide a citation for the 50%?

Comment: My source is MythBusters: https://www.facebook.com/MythBusters/posts/10150466971768224

Comment: That is atrociously irresponsible science journalism. The link they provide just takes you to some flashcards. I have no idea how they came up with that number. To get an idea of how people attempt to quantify homologous genomic material, [checkout this article](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3820096/).